# How do you handle unknown POINT values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, geospatial, point, mysql-5.7, spatial-index

MySQL 5.7 introduced Spatial Indexes on `POINT` columns. Apparently, you cannot have `NULL` values in a spatial index. At the same time, you cannot use a `DEFAULT` for `POINT` columns.

**So how do you handle the case where the value for `POINT` is unknown?**

I geocode every address in my database, but if the end user doesn't supply an address, what should I put there?

In another question, someone suggested placing them at the North Pole `POINT(0.0000,90.0000)` but this takes 25 bytes for each unknown address.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: You could put the points in another table, and use a foreign key in this table to reference them. You can make the foreign key nullable.

Comment: The column will use the same space regardless of value, even if the column were nullable, it would still use the same amount of space. Is space really the issue? Even though the north pole is an unlikely location, to ease queries, I would suggest adding a column to indicate if an address is available as a tiny int(1). Set to 1 if the address is valid/available, and 0 when missing.